# WSO2 Api Manager Application for several users

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Here is my problem : I'm tring to create an application which could be seen from the store by different users. I create the application "app1" with "user1" and i want "user2" to "join" the application "app1".
So is it possible to relate some users to an existing application ? If it is, can anyone explain me please because i don't see how to do it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From API Manager 1.9.0 onwards there is a feature called application sharing. Your expectation can be achieved by that. Please refer this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Sharing+Applications+and+Subscriptions).